# function to iterated through summation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataset.

One looks like this:

```
model <- data.frame(Variable = c("P_ALC", "P_ALC_BEER", "P_ALC_LIQUOR", 
"P_ALC_WINE", "P_BEAN", "P_LUNCH"), Estimate = c(0.0728768079454515, 
0.189831156431574, 0.182511704261063, 0.176711987960571, 0.0108000123096659, 
-0.00463222009211804))
```

The other looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(P_ALC = c(0.044, 0.001, 2.295, 0.55, 0.063, 1.604, 
0.584, 0.211, 0, 0.244), P_ALC_BEER = c(0.02, 0, 0.177, 0.53, 
0.02, 0.53, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.02), P_ALC_LIQUOR = c(0.022, 0, 0, 
0, 0.022, 1.069, 0.583, 0, 0, 0.046), P_ALC_WINE = c(0, 0, 2.118, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.004, 0, 0.202, 0, 0.177), P_BEAN = c(0.18, 0.133, 
0.182, 0.128, 0.06, 0.408, 0.066, 0.18, 0.757, 0.068), P_LUNCH = c(0.137, 
0.058, 0.107, 0.249, 0.037, 0.161, 0.542, 0.033, 0.029, 0.44))
```

I want to do the following calculation:

```
score <- model[1,2] + model[2,2]*data[model[2,1]]  + model[3,2]*data[model[3,1]]+ model[4,2]*data[model[4,1]]  + model[5,2]*data[model[5,1]] + model[6,2]*data[model[6,1]]
```

This works fine for my toy dataset. But in actuality the model data frame is around 80 rows long so i want to write a function that will keep counting through the rows without having to copy and past.

Comment: shouldn't `score` start with `model[1,2]*data[model[1,1]] +`  instead of `model[1,2] + `?

Comment: also... this looks like some sort of `lm` model where you extract the values of the coefficients and now you are trying to calculate new predictions... wouldn't you want instead to keep the model as it is (withouth extracting the coefficients) and use a `predict` functions on your new data?

Answer (score 4):

We may loop `across` the columns specified in 'Variable' column of 'model' except the first element, multiply with the corresponding 'Variable' value, get the `rowSums` and add the first element of 'Estimate'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(score = model$Estimate[1] + rowSums(across(all_of(model$Variable[-1]), 
      ~ . * model$Estimate[match(cur_column(), model$Variable)])))
```

-output

```
 P_ALC P_ALC_BEER P_ALC_LIQUOR P_ALC_WINE P_BEAN P_LUNCH      score
1  0.044      0.020        0.022      0.000  0.180   0.137 0.08199808
2  0.001      0.000        0.000      0.000  0.133   0.058 0.07404454
3  2.295      0.177        0.000      2.118  0.182   0.107 0.48222287
4  0.550      0.530        0.000      0.020  0.128   0.249 0.17725054
5  0.063      0.020        0.022      0.020  0.060   0.037 0.08469954
6  1.604      0.530        1.069      0.004  0.408   0.161 0.37295980
7  0.584      0.000        0.583      0.000  0.066   0.542 0.17748327
8  0.211      0.010        0.000      0.202  0.180   0.033 0.11226208
9  0.000      0.000        0.000      0.000  0.757   0.029 0.08091808
10 0.244      0.020        0.046      0.177  0.068   0.440 0.11504322
```